# Which DML Events Cause Trigger Recursion

Tags: trigger, recursion

I am curious, besides the `UPDATE` DML event causing trigger recursion (an update causing another update due to a field update), what other scenarios can result in trigger recursion.

I would like to know so I can be mindful of these scenarios when designing triggers in the future.

Comment: Closely related. Worth knowing the details of [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no correct answer to this question as it's always going to depend on what triggers and workflows are configured in a given org.

Like you say, updating the records being processed in an update trigger is likely to set off a waterfall, but so is insert in an insert, inserting in an update when there's an insert trigger etc., the number of scenarios is huge.

You could have a trigger on insert of Object A that inserts a record of Object B, which then creates an insert of Object A... the list goes on and on.

The best way to protect yourself is to use a trigger framework, a decent naming scheme, and implement recursion control in triggers that could be at risk.

Comment: Interesting that you brought up the trigger framework,  since this is the reason I asked this question. Thank you for the great answer; it clears things up a lot.